# Does list comprehension always create a list in Python?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

For example, if I have something like:

```
sum([i for i in range(very_big_number)])
```

Will this construction be optimized for reducing memory cost?

Comment: No, Python will create a very big list, call `sum`, and then discard the list

Comment: why not use n * (n+1)/2

Comment: Use generator expression.

Comment: some functions like `str.join` and `sort` will recreate the list anyway. But not `sum`

Comment: Guys, don't take into account range(very_big_number). It's just an example, not real task.

Comment: now you have 2 good answers. Please accept one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - so what you probably want is a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/).

```
sum(i for i in range(very_big_number))
```

As others have noted, you'll need `xrange` in Python 2.

As an additional benefit, you omit *any* additional syntax tokens, so it looks slightly neater :)

Comment: make it `sum(range(very_big_number))`

Comment: Yes, definitely neater for _that_ example;  I wanted to keep the generator  expression as the question is about list comprehensions in the general case

Comment: Yes, that's what I needed. I think there's a small difference in memory usage, but better than with list comprehension

Answer (score 1):

This will indeed always create a large list, assuming you are using a typical implementation of Python such as the standard CPython:

```
sum([i for i in range(very_big_number)])
```

These will avoid creating the list (in Python 2 you'll need `xrange()` instead):

```
sum(i for i in range(very_big_number))
sum(range(very_big_number))
```

Comment: `i for i in range(very_big_number)` is overkill for `range(very_big_number)`